# Getting external JSON data using fetch in REACT?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to build a REACT webpage that displays information loaded into a .json file that is constantly being added/removed by a separate Python script.

My problem is that I cannot seem to properly fetch the JSON information, it always returns a promise that I can't seem to parse the values out of - preventing my code further down from using the .map function on it.

```
// A card used to store warrant information
const WarrantCard = () => {
    let JSONDataPromise = fetch('data/ingame.json').then(response =>
        response.json().then(data => ({
            data: data,
            status: response.status
        }))
    )
    console.log(JSONDataPromise)
    let JSONData = JSONDataPromise.then(function(value){
        return value
    })
    console.log("Is the JSON Data loaded correctly?")
    console.log(JSONData)
    console.log("By now hopefully it is?")
    return (
        <div>
            {JSONData.map((postDetail)=>{
                // Using the data from our .json file, fill in the fields in our WarrantCards
```

This is what I get when I output the log: [image]

I've tried a bunch of different solutions from online but none seem to work. Full disclaimer I am very new to js and really don't have any clue what I am doing yet.

Comment: I might take a quick step back and hunt for that clue ;) Your `fetch` already has a `then` handler: it is there you'd set some component state used for rendering later. However what you likely *actually* want is a `useEffect` to fetch that only once rather than on every render. There are tutorials that cover how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React' main feature is **states**. Basically everything revolves around it. So what you need to do is is create a state in which you can store your JSON data. Initially you won't have any data because you're component hasn't rendered yet and therefor hasn't been able to *download* the data.

With the `useEffect` hook you can take action whenever a change in state happens, whenever the component is mounted and or whenever the componen is dismounted. The first parameter is the function you need to call whene a change happens. By passing an empty array `[]` as the second parameter you indicate to the component that the function in `useEffect` should be called whenever the component renders for the **first** time. This is the point where you want to get your data.

Then, after you got your data, update the state you've created earlier. This change in state will cause a rerender. But because the state now has data, it can render something based on that data.

```
const WarrantCard = () => {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState(null);

  const getJsonData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('data/ingame.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getJsonData().then(data => {
      setJsonData(data);
    }); 
  }, []);

  if (jsonData === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {jsonData.map(({ user, tags, server }) => {
        ...
      })};
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works, but how would I get the page to re-render when the contents of the .json file change/when the file gets saved or updated? With this method, the page stays the same even after the .json changes?

Answer (score 0):

React is a front-end framework that runs in the browser. Browser code, by design, cannot access the file system. It would have to call some other code (back-end code) that reads the contents of the file, and returns it to the front end.

At that point, you're outside the framework. React is mostly concerned about drawing things on the screen, and keeping track internally of what's changed and updating parts of the screen that have changed. You would use a non-React library to call the back end to get JSON updates, and then put that into React variables (states) that then update the appearance of screen objects.

If you want to push changes from the server to the front end, you could employ WebSockets on the back end and connect to it from the front end. But again, this is outside of React -- you'd have to use a third-party WebSockets library.

Or, you could periodically poll the back end to ask if anything has changed, and then update the React variables if something has changed.

Anyway, reading an external file is very far away from what React was designed to do. I know that the explanation above was a bit abstract, but hopefully it makes some sense.

Comment: Yeah I realized tonight that my understanding of what REACT was for is completely wrong, thank you for helping clarify haha

Comment: OK, cool. Best of luck with your project!